# Referencing Two Tables in SQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, how could I answer the following question?  Do I use join?
Thank you so much.

What are the names and home cities for people searched for the word "drain"?

.schema is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR,
  `email` VARCHAR,
  `city` VARCHAR,
  `state` VARCHAR,
 `last_visit` DATE,
 `page_views` INTEGER,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `search_terms` (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `word` VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select u.name, u.city
    from users u
    inner join search_terms st on st.id = u.id
    where st.word = 'drain'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Whenever I try that, I get no output.  I tried removing the where part too, and I still get no output.  Why is this? Thanks again

Comment: the terminal goes from having this sqlite>  to    ...>  after i try it.

Comment: @Lanie909 , I just tested it on Fiddle using SQLite - no errors.  Is there definitely a match for 'drain'?

Comment: So sorry about that, syntax error on my end.  It works great. Thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

You do need to join search_terms table with users table. I assume the search_terms.id is referencing to users.id. 
Linking them both, will give us the results of the search terms for each user. 
from there you can add more filters (WHERE conditions) to have more specific results.

So, to get the names and the home cities for each user you need to select name and city from users table, then join search_terms table and link id columns to know what words that each user has used in the search.

The query should be something like this :

```
SELECT name, city
FROM users
LEFT JOIN search_terms ON search_terms.id = users.id 
WHERE 
    search_terms.word LIKE 'drain';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `JOIN` or a sub-query.  Here's the basic strategy:

1. Get the `id` values that match what you're looking for
2. Look up any other info for those `id` values

.

```
SELECT name, city
FROM users usr
INNER JOIN search_terms stm ON usr.id = stm.id
WHERE stm.word = 'drain';
```

or ...

```
SELECT name, city
FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM search_terms WHERE word = 'drain');
```